# SQL how to group by ID and create another column based on value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to SQL and I would like to to group by ID and create another column based on value.

Let me give an example:

| Foreign ID | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'X' | 10 |
| 1 | 'Y' | 20 |
| 2 | 'X' | 30 |
| 2 | 'Y' | 40 |

My expected output would be

| Foreign ID | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 20 |
| 2 | 30 | 40 |

Answer (score 0):

Grouping is done with [Group By](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-group-by/). And making a column out of a row, which is what the example shows is done with [Crosstab function](https://ubiq.co/database-blog/create-pivot-table-postgresql/).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a basic Left Join should do: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-left-join/

Also, write the code, it hepls.